# Find the maximum eigenvalue

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Is there any analytic method to find out the maximum eigenvalue given any square matrix? Or can I find out any information about the maximum eigenvalue given a square matrix?

If not, what if the matrix is specified to be a [Laplacian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) corresponding to a graph?

EDIT:
I know there is a standard way to calculate the eigenvalues of a square matrix, i.e. the roots of $|\lambda I - A |= 0$. But what if this matrix is of a very large dimension? Is there a more explicit or easier way to find out the **maximum eigenvalue in particular**?

Comment: There's the maximum value of $xAx/|x|$, which gives said value. This, with some analysis, gives meaning to the graph case you mentioned, though I can't recall what the largest value gives... The smaller are related to connectedness iirc

Comment: Given a square matrix, you may find _all_ eigenvalues and whatever else you want. Arguably, the maximum eigenvalue is also the easiest to find.

Comment: @IvanNeretin I know there is a standard way to calculate the eigenvalues of a square matrix, e.g. $|\lambda I - A |= 0$. But what if this matrix of a very large dimension? Is it a more explicit or easier way to find out the maximum eigenvalue in particular? Thank you for this comment which helps me clarify my question.

Comment: @ArtimisFowl you mean the Rayleigh Quotient theorem.

Comment: Do you mean numerically or analytically ? In the first case, the power method can help you. In the second case, you are looking for the largest root of a polynomial of a high degree and there is no closed-form formula.